# Visualizar salida de aplicación desde otra aplicación Win form C#

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Estoy creando una aplicación WinForm en C# con Visual Studio 2019, desde una opción de menú en el Form principal, activo un proceso que lanza otra aplicación windows, MSBuild.exe :

```
    Process.Start("%PROGRAMFILES(X86)%\'Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin'\MSBuild.exe");
```

El MSBuild.exe compila un proyecto web y va mostrando en consola D.O.S. en varias líneas los resultados. Lo que quiero lograr es capturar esos mensajes de salida e ir mostrándola en un Panel con un textbox, un Panel o lo que sea más conveniente desde el form principal de mi aplicación, hasta que finalice, pero no recuerdo como hacerlo, hace rato que no hago aplicaciones Winform.
Muchas gracias

Comment: Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Revisa [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes. ¿Qué panel? ¿cuál textbox?

Comment: Hola @Alfabravo, gracias por responder, no agregué más código porque a mi parecer, era innecesario, en mi mensaje explico claramente (eso creo) lo que quiero hacer, lo que tengo y que espero obtener, la única línea de código que puse es lo único que agregué al código generado automáticamente por el Visual Studio al seleccionar el proyecto de WinForm, pero si hay que agregar todo el código, lo agrego. Nuevamente, gracias

Comment: Pues sólo te digo que, si esperas una respuesta concreta donde te digan cómo modificar tu código para cargar esa info en esos componentes (o en otros porque ahí no se puede, lo que sea), es más fácil a partir de tu código. Por eso te puse el enlace de Cómo preguntar, no se trata de que te respondan en el aire sobre un caso hipotético (porque ya ha pasado incontables veces que dicen _probé lo que me dices y me da error_). Ofrece en la pregunta un ejemplo mínimo de lo que intentas.